# Meaning of comma in converting to Percentage

Tags: python

```
x = 0.3333

print(f"{x:,.2%}")
```

I found the output is the same without the comma in the print, which is:

```
print(f"{x:.2%}")
```

so what's the meaning of this comma here (the one between colon and period)?

Answer (score 0):

Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The `','` option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator. For a locale aware separator, use the `'n'` integer presentation type instead.

```
x = 1000.3333

print(f"{x:.2%}")  # 100033.33%
print(f"{x:,.2%}")  # 100,033.33%
```